# Extract multiple strings between two strings

Tags: python, string

I would like to be able to extract a string between two strings

Input:

```
one_string = " ‘name’:’john’,’phone’:’8947467’,’name’:’anthony’,’phone’:’74729’ "

Names are between strings: ‘name’:’ and ’

Phones are between strings: ’phone’:’ and ’
```

Output:

```
names = 'john','anthony'
phones = '8947467','74729'
```

Any thoughts? It may be very easy, but I am lost.

Thanks

Comment: well but where is the code you've tried so far

Comment: the thought is regex.  I suggest reading up on that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `re.findall`:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

one_string = " ’name’:’john’,’phone’:’8947467’,’name’:’anthony’,’phone’:’74729’ "
names = re.findall(r'’name’:’(.*?)’', one_string)
phones = re.findall(r'’phone’:’(.*?)’', one_string)
print("names =  " + ','.join(names))
print("phones = " + ','.join(phones))
```

This prints:

```
names =  john,anthony
phones = 8947467,74729
```

Note: Your sample input seems to not always use consistent curly quotes.  I have fixed this in my answer as I saw made the most sense.

Comment: Question. Can you please explain `(.*?)` in the regexp?

Comment: @balderman It is lazy `.*`, which means match until reaching the first (nearest) curly quote.  If we _didn't_ use lazy dot, then it would match across name/phone pairs in the string, which we don't want.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand it well. In case of  `names` the first match will stop at `‘name’:’john’` (last curly quote). and it starts at `‘name’:’`

Comment: Yes, just test out my script using `(.*)` instead of `(.*?)` to see what happens yourself.

Comment: I tried - the match grabbed the rest of the string starting from `‘name’:’`. So `?` made it lazy here?